# Calling a function from ajax in WordPress

Tags: ajax, wordpress

I have a category list in the WP job manager and I have created a function in the functions.php file

```
function category_select_list(){
    $cat_list = '';
    foreach ( get_job_listing_categories() as $cat ) {
       $cat_list .= '<option value="'. esc_attr( $cat->slug ).'">'.esc_html( 
       $cat->name ).'</option>';
    }

   echo  $cat_list;
   exit();
 }
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_category_select_list', 'category_select_list');
add_action('wp_ajax_category_select_list', 'category_select_list');
```

then in my site.js file, I check to see if a form is in the page and then make an ajax call to return the data from the function.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() { // wait for page to finish loading
if($('#mc4wp-form-1').length){
     jQuery.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php",
        data: {
            action: 'get_category_list'
        },
         success:function(output){
             alert(output);
         },
         error: function(errorThrown){
             alert(errorThrown);
         }
     });
   }
});
```

The ajax is alerting a zero, not an error. I don't know what the issue is. I have changed the php function to just echo a "hello" to test that it's not the php function but it still alerts a '0'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The action you're calling should have the same name as the action you set in your function.php (`wp_ajax_category_select_list`, without the prefix `wp_ajax_`). The action in your js should be: `action: 'category_select_list'`

You should also use the function `wp_die()` instead of the `exit()`.

More on the subject: https://codex.wordpress.org/AJAX_in_Plugins#Ajax_on_the_Administration_Side

Comment: Thanks I didnt realise I was calling a function that didnt exist...DOH! thanks for pointing that out. I still needed the wp_ajax prefix for it 5to twork though

Answer (score 1):

Your action is "get_category_list".

so your add_action should be like this.

```
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_get_category_list', 'category_select_list');
add_action('wp_ajax_get_category_list', 'category_select_list');
```

Thanks.